# crossplatform in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

`iOS` in `Xamarin`

Postby Zecht1 » Fri Dec 13, 2013 1:26 pm
Hi

I just begun learning `Xamarin` and I'm following the tutorials on their site at http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,_world/

I have a problem and I want some help!

It says in the tutorial that I should write the code in this manner:

```
partial void actnButtonClick (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)
{
    this.lblOutput.Text = "Action button " +  ((UIButton)sender).CurrentTitle + " clicked.";
}
```

But this does not work for me. I just get an error.

Mine looks like this:

```
partial void actnButtonClick (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender);
```

Did I do something wrong???

The error messages:

http://s23.postimg.org/mp1niokij/Screen_Shot_2013_12_13_at_5_09_07_PM.png

http://s2.postimg.org/fy5n9im95/Screen_Shot_2013_12_13_at_5_09_29_PM.png

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Original answer deleted following addition of screenshots.

I see the problem now that you've added screenshots.  You can't modify the .designer.cs file.  It even says at the top of the screenshot you've put on, "Manual changes to this file may not be handled correctly."

I don't know what you've called your file, but assuming the main file is called HelloWorld.cs you'd need to make the following changes:

**HelloWorld.designer.cs:**

```
[Action ("acOneBtnClick:")]
partial void acOneBtnClick(MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender);
```

This part should be automatically created by Xamarin.

**HelloWorld.cs:**

```
partial void acOneBtnClick(MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)
{
    this.ibiOutput.Text = "Action button" + ((UIButton)sender).CurrentTitle + " clicked.";
}
```

Methods and classes that are declared `partial` can be implemented in separate files.  See [MSDN partial (Method)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8.aspx) for more information.

Comment: The error messages:

http://s23.postimg.org/mp1niokij/Screen_Shot_2013_12_13_at_5_09_07_PM.png

http://s2.postimg.org/fy5n9im95/Screen_Shot_2013_12_13_at_5_09_29_PM.png

Thanks for your help